# Determining which config file a setting originated from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, web-config

I am trying to find a way to determine the location of the config file that holds a specific appsetting or connection string value. i.e. I have multiple web sites/apps on an IIS server and I would like to determine if a setting is coming from the app's config, the parent app's config or the machine.config.

Any idea?
TIA
J

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically, at runtime?

Comment: Yes I want to do it programmatically at runtime. The idea is to provide a quick tool for our tech support crew to use to determine if an app is picking up the settings they expect.

Comment: see my 'Note:' in my answer. 4.0 framework stores the settings in a different file after the product has been installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that using `System.Configuration` because it was designed to be indiscriminate. If you must do what you are trying to do, you will want to manually parse the potential files, those being the app.config/web.config, application.exe.config, and machine.config.

**Note:** I see you are using .NET 4.0. Note that 4.0 uses *application*.exe.config instead of the older app.config or web.config, where *application* is your actual EXE file's name, to read its settings after the product has been installed through a setup.

Comment: I am just trying to make a simple tool for our tech support team to use to confirm that they are getting the settings from the configs they think they are.

Comment: @John. Oh, I see. I think you will have to manually parse the config files and use the hardcoded logic of which file otherrides the other to create your tool.

Comment: That seems to confirm what I have been finding. I was just hoping that someone had found a simple way. Thanks for your input.